# I have a String (( Relationship=11 ) AND ( Relationship=12 ) AND ( Relationship=1 ))

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to extract the values 11,12 and 1 i.e the value just **after =**.
I am trying to do the following

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

And then I will split using `=`

Is there some better way to do it?

Comment: `("(\\\d+)")` should work

Comment: @Jens Two backslashes are enough.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ok  i was not sure. That's why it is a comment not an answer :)

Comment: If you are really working on such static expressions, regex is a good weapon. When you are parsing something like a programming language, you should consider building a lexer for it.

Comment: @Jens The regex itself is `\d`, but since in Java one backslash is an *escape character*, you should escape it, resulting in two.

Comment: As a side note, stackexchange has a site for reviewing code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex `=(\d+)` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/11rQh9/1)), which match one or more digit after the `=` like this:

```
String str = "(( Relationship=11 ) AND ( Relationship=12 ) AND ( Relationship=1 ))";
String regex = "=(\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Outputs**

```
11
12
1
```